# In Doctor Who, how is Osgood still alive in season 9?

Tags: doctor-who

In season 8 episode 12, Death In Heaven, when

> Missy/The Master is breaking out of the airplane, she kills Osgood while teasing her.

I've been thinking, how then are both Osgoods still alive in season 9 episode 8, The Zygon Invasion, if the above occurred?

It doesn't make any sense to me. Could it probably be just a script error?

Comment: I think the confusion is, you're watching those videos showing both, but those were recorded before one of them died.  Only one Osgood survived, and only one shows up in the flesh, through the Invasion/Inversion story arc, up until the ending, and that is explained properly in the episode..

Comment: Exactly that was my problem. I must've missed the part where that was explained. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**It's not a script error. One Osgood was killed, but the other one survived.**

This is clearly explained in the first episode featuring Osgood since *Death in Heaven*:

> CLARA: **So, Osgood's been kidnapped, right? I thought Osgood was dead.**
>   KATE: **There've always been two of her, ever since the ceasefire.** We never knew which one was real.
>   DOCTOR: Both of them.
>   KATE: Okay, which one was Zygon.
>   DOCTOR: Both of them. They would have maintained a live link. They were both Zygon and human at the same time. They not only administered the peace, they were the peace.
>   JAC: **When the other Osgood died, the survivor went pretty much mad with grief. Then she just disappeared. Went undercover in the States.** Now, of course, the rebels have her.
>
> <sub>-- Series 9 Episode 7, *The Zygon Invasion* (emphasis mine)</sub>

We saw at the very start of this episode that there had been two Osgoods ever since the events of *Day of the Doctor*:

> NARRATOR: Once upon a time, there were Three Doctors. Two Osgoods.
>
> [...]
>
> OSGOODS: Shall we do it together? Operation Double. The Zygon peace treaty.
>   OSGOOD 2: I'm Osgood.
>   OSGOOD 1: I'm also Osgood.
>   OSGOOD 2: Remember that. It'll be important later.
>
> <sub>-- Series 9 Episode 7, *The Zygon Invasion*</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Osgood and her Zygon "twin" had been sharing Osgood's life at that point, so we can't be sure whether the original Osgood was killed or if it was her Zygon duplicate. Either way, the other lived on into series 9.

In episode 7, "The Zygon Invasion", we see a recording that was made before one of the Osgoods was killed (likely shortly after the relevant events of "The Day of the Doctor") which sets up this episode and the one to follow.

In episode 8, "The Zygon Inversion", Bonnie replaces the missing Osgood so that there are two again. We don't know if one is the original Osgood, or if they're both Zygons at this point.

Comment: There was no replacement. There were two Osgoods from the beginning of the treaty, along with two Osgood boxes.

Comment: We know that the zygon Osgood dies and not the human Osgood because in The 50th Special they find out who is who when human Osgood needs an inhaler, but zygon Osgood doesn't. In the beginning of season 9 episode 7 we see the remaining Osgood use her inhaler while she's waiting to be discovered under the desk, which means she's human Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The real Osgood survived. The clue is in the final episode of series 8 when she gets the cloud base reference wrong.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain how the accepted answer, that they were both Osgoode, is wrong?  Also, adding the exact quote will make this a better answer.